# How to override css in material UI?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material UI with reactjs. I want to override button color but in my case it changes tabs color also (see screenshot) how can I override button color only, using themes in material UI ? 
Code:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#DDB61A',
        },
        secondary: {
            main: '#1d83c6',
        },
    },
});


<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <AppBar position="static">
           <Tabs value={value} onChange={this.handleTabChange}>
           <Tab label="USDT" />
           <Tab label="BTC" />
           <Tab label="ETH" />
           </Tabs>
        </AppBar>

    {value === 0 && <TabContainer>
    <Button variant="contained" color="primary" fullWidth={true}>
              Buy/Login
         </Button>
    </TabContainer>}
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

2nd approach also doesn't work:

```
    const theme = createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
            myBtn: {
                main: '#DDB61A',
            }
        }
    });

<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>    
    <Button variant="contained" color="myBtn" fullWidth={true}>
          Buy/Login
    </Button>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can customize the style of a component using overrides:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#ce93d8', // main color
        },
        secondary: {
            main: '#1d83c6',
        },
    },
    overrides: {
        MuiButton: { // Name of the component ⚛️ / style sheet
            root: { // Name of the rule
                background: '#DDB61A', // Some CSS
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Check this page: https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/

Comment: The link is dead, any ideas where is best to read about this now?

Comment: Huh, when I click it I'm seeing a Page Not Found error: https://pasteboard.co/Ikjcdhw.png

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here is changing the entire theme. There are a number of ways to change the style of specific elements, or all the appearances of a specific element in your app.

In your case, if you are trying to change the color for one button, you can use override classes like so:

```
const buttonStyle = (theme) => ({
    root: {
        background: 'red'
    },
});

const StyledButton = (props) => withStyles(styles)(
    <Button classes={{root}}/>
);
```

If you want to override all of the buttons, you can do that with a customized theme:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export const createCustomTheme = () => theme => {
  return createMuiTheme({
    ...theme,

    overrides: {
      MuiButton: {
        root: {
          background: 'red'
        }
      },
    }

  });
};

export default creatCustomTheme();
```

Comment: I couldn't understand you could can you please elaborate? Why are you passing props. Lets say if I have 3 buttons and all 3 of them should have different colors how can I do that ?

Comment: I've added a custom theme example to my answer. That way all of the buttons are overriden from within your theme.

Comment: I don;t want all buttons some buttons I want default color some I want to have different colors ,in that case, what should I do ? Because changing theme will affect all the buttons ? I want to change a few buttons to red few buttons to some other custom color

Comment: There are many ways. You can create a styled button with a few variants, each using it's own class to change the color. Or you can create a styled button that takes the color as a prop.

Comment: Where are you using MuiButton ? I couldn't understand that

Comment: `MuiButton` is the theme override class. Button is the component you import from `@material-ui/core`

Answer (score 0):

Create a new color variant in ur palette:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#DDB61A',
        },
        secondary: {
            main: '#1d83c6',
        },
        tertiary: {
            main: '#000',
        },
    },
});
```

and then:

```
<Button variant="contained" color="tertiary" fullWidth={true}>
              Buy/Login
         </Button>
```

Comment: Can I add any random name inside of primary, secondary,  tertiary eg: myBtn and then use it color="myBtn" but this doesn't work.

Comment: @funjoker You should be able to use random names. Did my code not work?

Comment: It doesn't work see my edited question above. 2nd approach also doesn't work

Comment: check this link: https://imgur.com/a/IMVmEsm and this https://material-ui.com/api/button/

Answer (score 0):

If someone still comes to this question:
The solution for MUI v5 to globaly override components is documented here: [Global style overrides](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#global-style-overrides)